# Escape the symbols in JSON object

Tags: json, jsoncpp

I have this JSON object

```
{'zone1': [{'detected_people': {'coordinates': [[21, 0], [16, 4], [23, 4], [21, 6], [16, 21]]}, 'gridOrigin': [28.5, 20.6], 'gridScale': 0.5, 'gridSizeX': 50, 'gridSizeY': 50, 'stamp': '2020-08-28 21:06:48', 'zoneID': 'shop1'}]}
```

I can't submit to webservice database.
My server side suggested me to `escape the symbols`.

I am creating JSON object using `jsoncpp` as follows.

```
struct JSON_PEOPLE{
   //Json::Value root;
   Json::Value zone_1;   
   Json::Value zone_2;
   Json::Value zone1;   
   Json::Value zone2;
   Json::Value coord;
   Json::Value gridOrigin;
   
   JSON_PEOPLE(){
     zone1["zoneID"] = "shop1";
     zone1["stamp"] = "##########";
     zone1["gridSizeX"]=50;
     zone1["gridSizeY"]=50;
     zone1["gridScale"]=0.5;
     zone1["gridOrigin"].append(28.5);
     zone1["gridOrigin"].append(20.6);
     

     zone2["zoneID"] = "shop2";
     zone2["stamp"] = "##############";
     zone2["gridSizeX"]=50;
     zone2["gridSizeY"]=50;
     zone2["gridScale"]=0.5;
     zone2["gridOrigin"].append(35.5);
     zone2["gridOrigin"].append(40.6);
   }
}
```

How can I escape symbols?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes for all strings and property names. How is it created?

Comment: Created JSON using JSONCPP and my C code has interface to Python. Json string was sent to Python and I used  json.loads(info) to convert Json string to JSON object. That json.loads changed all double quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have correct JSON string.

```
{
    "zone1" : 
    [
        {
            "detected_people" : 
            {
                "coordinates" : 
                [
                    [
                        22,
                        3
                    ],
                    [
                        21,
                        6
                    ],
                    [
                        16,
                        21
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "gridOrigin" : 
            [
                28.5,
                20.600000000000001
            ],
            "gridScale" : 0.5,
            "gridSizeX" : 50,
            "gridSizeY" : 50,
            "stamp" : "2020-08-28 22:23:05",
            "zoneID" : "shop1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When converted to JSON object, I have to do `json_obj = json.dumps(json.loads(info))`. So I have correct double quotes.